# how to check if the protobuf message is set?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message as follows:

```
message result
{
    repeated data;
    repeated warning;
    repeated error;
}
```

I have a code which on SUCCESS: sets the data and warnings(if any) and
on FAILURE: sets the error.

I want to create the following response:

```
SUCCESS: {"data":[\{"status":200,"title":"parameter set successfully."\}],"warnings:[]}
FAILURE: {"errors":[\{"status":400,"code":16075,"title":"Invalid parameter specified."\}]}
```

In conclusion, I want to check if there is "error" in response message, data field should not be added. I tried with hasField() but did not work.

Please help me in finding a solution for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but in general for repeated fields, check the list size instead of using the "hasField()" you mentioned.

Question was tagged with `c++`, so the C++ example would be:

```
if (result.error_size() > 0)
  // There are errors.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it but does not work. The response is of type "google::protobuf::Message". Is there any function supported by descriptor or message class to check if the error field is set?

Comment: What about the FieldSize method described in https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.message/. Does that work for you?